# getDefaultSensor(SENSOR_TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION) returns null

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm trying to use the significant motion sensor but getting:

`mysensor.getDefaultSensor(SENSOR_TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION)`

as null.

How to check whether this sensor is available on phone or simulator?

Thanks in advance
-Vaibhav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

if (sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION) != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Sensor is available");
}
```

Comment: Thanks...at-least it should be present in the simulator..isn't it..?